# autocomplete extender problem?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using autocomplete extender, i write a webservice the webservice is working fine when i run webservice. But when i run my aspx page it is not displaying any thing the autocomplete is not showing only text box is there. this is my code......

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{

    SqlConnection con;SqlDataAdapter da;
    public WebService () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public string[] GetTitleInfo(string prefixText)
{
    int count = 10;
    string sqry = "select * from news_upload where newstitle like @prefixText";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqry, "server=localhost;database=tfcnew;user id=sa;password=sql123");
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = prefixText + "%";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    string[] items = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        items.SetValue(dr["newstitle"].ToString (), i);
        i++;
    }
    return items;
}
```

this is (above) service.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcomplete" runat ="Server" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender2" runat="server" MinimumPrefixLength ="1" ServiceMethod ="GetSuggestions" ServicePath="~/WebService2.asmx" TargetControlID ="txtcomplete" >
        </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

This is aspx code..

can u help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]" before the class declaration

```
[System.Web.WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")] 
[System.Web.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)] 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {
...
...
...
```

if it is already in your code, You could check the service path. Use Fiddler or Firebug to see if there is an actual call to the service. if not working then set the servicepath from paga_Load event of your aspx page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load  
   If Not Page.IsPostBack() Then
      AutoCompleteExtender2.ServicePath = ResolveUrl("~/mywebservice.asmx")                    
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it seems ok as it is working independently. I have edited the answer for you. you could use fiddler and could check the result of your request